# GROUP BY с сортировкой по полю

Tags: mysql, сортировка, sql

В таблице `Table1` есть поля: `IdRecordstouser`, `StatusRecordstouser`.
Нужно сгруппировать по полю `IdRecordstouser` так, чтобы на выходе была строка с `StatusRecordstouser = 1`.

Пробую так:

```
GROUP BY  IdUserRecordstouser order by IdRecordstouser, StatusRecordstouser DESC
```

Comment: И? В чём вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что нужно на выходе получить отсортированные строки по  StatusRecordstouser = 1, если есть такие.

Comment: WHERE StatusRecordstouser = 1?

Comment: Нет, сгруппированные и отсортированные по StatusRecordstouser. Т.е. если StatusRecordstouser  = 1, то строка на самом верху.

Comment: Это как раз тот случай, когда UNION тут неплохой вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и писать

```
order by StatusRecordstouser = 1
```

**UPD:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a60b7b/4

Answer (score 0):

Если я понял вопрос, то группировка вам не нужна, а нужна только сортировка по двум столбцам:

```
order by IdRecordstouser, StatusRecordstouser DESC
```

Уберите GROUP BY.